# Gnome-Screenshot GUI: Which command launches that?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, screenshot

I'm interested in setting up a keyboard shortcut that will launch the graphical user interface for Gnome Screenshot. I am however unable to find the command that launches the GUI.

Executing `gnome-screenshot` simply takes a screenshot, which is not what I am interested in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may look for interactive mode

`man gnome-screenshot`

> ```
>   -i, --interactive
> ```

```
          Interactively set options in a dialog.
```

Use:

```
gnome-screenshot -i
```

More generally, to get command for a GUI launcher in menu, look for its `.desktop` file. Example:

```
more /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop
```

Where we see:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Screenshot
Comment=Save images of your screen or individual windows
(...)
Exec=gnome-screenshot --interactive  # <-- here it is!
(...)
```

Or use *MenuLibre* tool.

---

Update: As of [v41 (November 2021)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/-/blob/master/NEWS), the path to the `.desktop` file for Gnome Screenshot was changed from `/usr/share/applications/gnome-screenshot.desktop` in the original answer.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. I've been looking through `--help` three times. Thank you!

Comment: I liked `gnome-screenshot -a -c` to capture a portion of the screen and automatically send it to the clipboard where I can paste it into my notes.

Comment: @Rasmus Happens to me all the time. Sometimes I even forget to scroll through the `man` entry, too impatient!

Answer (score 3):

For other screenshot options without opening the GUI:

`gnome-screenshot -a`  Grab a user selected area of the screen

`gnome-screenshot -w`  Grab a window instead of the entire screen

`gnome-screenshot -c`  Send screen grab directly to the clipboard

---

For additional options, in the terminal type your command -help

`gnome-screenshot -help`

Comment: To be exact, I guess that the command is  `--help` — from the output:  `-h, --help                     Show help options`.